# Loop over an interval of files

Tags: cmd

I would like to define a for-loop (windows command line) that iterates over (numbered) intervals of files in a directory, say 1..100, and then 101..200, and 201..300 etc [***Edit***: regardless of the files names]. See following pseudo-code:

```
for %WORKDIR% %%f(1..100) in (*.htm) do (
   REM DoSomething with %%f
)

for %WORKDIR% %%f(101..200) in (*.htm) do (
   REM DoSomething with %%f
)

...etc
```

**Q:** Is there a way to define "numbered intervals" of files from command line?

// Rolf

Comment: nor sure, if I understand your question. Do you want to process files in bunches of 100, regardless of their name?

Comment: Yes, in bunches ("numbered intervals"), that is, regardless of file name. A constraint is that I plan to run those intervals concurrently, which is the very reason for the "intervals" in the first place. Notice that the example above would process the files sequentially (but I would call the "intervals" from different batch files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place each function in a separate file:

```
:1to100
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a "file=1"

rem Skip 0 (skip=0 is omitted because it's illegal) and process 100.
for /f %%f in ('dir %workdir%\*.htm /b') do (
    if !file! gtr 100 (exit /b) else (set /a "file+=1")
    echo Do something with %%f.
)

endlocal
goto :eof

:100to200
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a "file=1"

rem Skip 100 and process 100.
for /f "skip=100" %%f in ('dir %workdir%\*.htm /b') do (
    if !file! gtr 100 (exit /b) else (set /a "file+=1")
    echo Do something with %%f.
)

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this asap and then be back if it solved my problem.